# Should I use Threads or multiple processess?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I wanted to get some help with an application... Currently I have a script that saves certain information to a database table, well call this table "x". I have another script that gets and saves other info to a different database table, well call this one "y". I also have a script that runs formulas on the information found in table y and I have another script that opens the link found in table x and saves certain information into table "z".

The problem I have is that the first script doesn't end, and neither does the third script. So I know now that I need to have either threads or multiple processes running but which one do I choose?

Script 1 accesses table W & X
Script 2 accesses table X & Y
Script 3 accesses table Y
Script 4 accesses table Z

Can you please give me some guidance on how to proceed?

Comment: Do these scripts share common (or global) variables? Do these scripts pass parameters or objects to one another?

Comment: Threads make it easy to communicate between scripts because threads share the same memory space. Therefore locks are easy to implement.

Comment: Hmmm... No they don't share or pass variables to each-other. They are separate and designed to run independently. They are designed to do different tasks. But I should be more detailed, Script 1 for example, passes variables/parameters to script 1.1 and 1.2 and so on. Script 2 does get, using django, variables from the database that are saved from script 1

Answer (score 0):

Based on Harp's second comment to his original post *(which was posted **after** your answer),* I suspect that you would now agree with me that *processes* are probably called-for here, based on this newly-supplied information.

However, I find myself questioning just how much "truly effective concurrency" is likely to be found here. This sounds like a *job* to me: a "script 1" (with its sub-scripts 1.1, 1.2 *etc.),* which prepares a file of inputs that is then delivered to "script 2." Especially since "script 2" is utterly beholden to an external web-site for what *it* does, I'm just not yet persuaded that the added complexity of "multi-threading" is genuinely justifiable here.

Comment: I totally agree with you. It sounds like a pipeline (no not the unix pipes), where scripts are dependent on the data generated by previous scripts.